# Create a splayed table in q

Tags: kdb

I have a table `trades` that I want to splay in the directory splay I have created.

From what I have researched, the correct syntax is:

```
`:splay/ set trades
```

I have tried this, however I get an error `'type`.

I've managed to save a flat table using:

```
`:splay/flattrades set trades
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is documented on the official doc site: https://code.kx.com/q/kb/splayed-tables/

The issue is likely that you haven't enumerated the symbol columns using `.Q.en`.

If you're still getting errors even after enumeration it could potentially be due to inconsistent datatypes within your columns (e.g. a column having a mixture of longs and ints). You can check this using something like:

```
distinct type''[trades]
```

assuming your trades table is an in-memory table. The above should return only one unique datatype for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Terry is very likely correct, the type error is due to trying to splay a table without ensuring the symbols are enumerated first. If for some reason you wish to bypass this (something I would not advise), you can just write the columns individually using something like the following.

**AGAIN, THIS IS NOT ADVISEABLE**. But it is a good exercise in understanding how to write to disk in kdb+

```
forceSplay:{[dir;tab] 
    {[d;t;c]@[d;c;:;t[c]]}[dir;0!tab;] each cols tab;
    @[dir;`.d;:;cols 0!tab]
 }
```

Here I'm using [@](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#apply-at-index-at) to apply the `set` function (which is represented as `:`) to the directories. The first step is to write each of the columns for the table individually, and the follow up is to write the `.d` column list file.